# use of Index over function SUM in DB2

Tags: indexing, db2, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I had a Query as Below,

```
SELECT SUM(SOLD_QTY_CNT) AS QUANTITY, DENOM_AM, SUM(LIN_AM) AS LINE_AMT,
    LIN_AM AS O_LINE_AMT, ORD_DTL_ID
    FROM MyTable    GROUP BY ORD_DTL_ID, LIN_AM, DENOM_AM
    WITH UR;
```

My Query is to optimize/better way to rewrite this Query.
Since it had an function SUM so hope creating index for all the columns involved will not help out.

when i took the access plan for the aove said query it comes `close to 70k..` since the table used is very large table.

So Please Suggest some way to optimise the query.

TIA.

Comment: Did you try the DB2 Design Advisor -- it may suggest an index that benefits your query, if it does not already exist.

Comment: Personally, I'd suspect an index on {`ORD_DTL_ID`, `LIN_AM`, `DENOM_AM`} (and possibly including `SOLD_QTY_CNT` as an additional column) would help - although you might be able to get better results if you 'cheat' on summing `LINE_AMT` (by doing `COUNT(*) * LIN_AM` - will depend on how the optimizer works).

Comment: clock - the select query have the function "SUM", so will index work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the ***db2advis tool***

```
    db2advis -d <database-name> -s "<your above query, try entering in one line>"
```

This would then suggest you with the creation of indexes and removal of the not needed ones. Follow the advises resulted out in it and that should do it.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the time and effort put.i tried run this,but i got an error
db2 => db2advis -d PWEBS00D -s SELECT SUM(SOLD_QTY_CNT) AS QUANTITY, DENOM_AM, SUM(LIN_AM) AS LINE_AMT,LIN_AM AS O_LINE_AMT, ORD_DTL_ID FROM WEBSS.P0066_SELECTION  GROUP BY ORD_DTL_ID, LIN_AM, DENOM_AM
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "db2advis -d PWEBS00D -s SELECT SUM" was found
following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:
"<table_keyword>".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: and also db2 => db2advis -d PWEBS00D -s "SELECT SUM(SOLD_QTY_CNT) AS QUANTITY, DENOM_AM, SUM(LIN_AM) AS LINE_AMT,LIN_AM AS O_LINE_AMT, ORD_DTL_ID FROM WEBSS.P0066_SELECTION  GROUP BY ORD_DTL_ID, LIN_AM, DENOM_AM"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "db2advis" was found following
"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "DECLARE".
SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Please suggest some way? is it another tool?? do i need to install anything?

Comment: @AProgrammer your entire Select query is supposed to be enclosed within double quotes or else it wouldn't recognize it as an sql query.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is DB2 for i, you might consider an [Encoded Vector Index](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzajq%2Fwhatareevi.htm). However, guessing by the names in your query, the cardinality of your composite key may be rather high for this approach.